# Найти все цифры в строке

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения

как найти все цифры в строке,с помощью какого метода если есть такой

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <regex>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        string str = "f52jnjn 7 8 h8";
        cmatch result;
        regex reg("([0-9])");
        if (regex_search(str.c_str(), result, reg)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++) {
                cout << result[i] << endl;
            }
        }
    }
```

данный метод ищет только первое совпадение,но как найти все совпадения

Answer (score 7, accepted):

На мой взгляд самый простой вариант std::isdigit - он проверит значение char на то является ли оно числом в нашем представлении или нет и вернет bool :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::string str{"f52jnjn 7 8 h8"};
    std::vector<unsigned char> res;

    for (unsigned char ch : str) {
        if (std::isdigit(ch)) {
            res.push_back(ch);
        }
    }

    if (res.empty()) {
        return -1;
    }

    auto shell_it(std::ostream_iterator<unsigned char>{std::cout, "\n"});
    std::copy(std::begin(res), std::end(res), shell_it);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ...это можно исправить, заменив цикл на `for (unsigned char ch : str)`.

Comment: @Abyx, разве? Это точно не только того, который с подчёркиванием касается?

Comment: @Qwertiy [*"The behavior is undefined if the value of ch is not representable as unsigned char and is not equal to EOF. "*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit). А с подчеркиванием - это какой?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat? хм.. я с _tolower попутал, кажется...

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        char ch[10];
        cin >> ch;


        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if ((ch[i] > 48) && (ch[i] < 57)) {
                cout << ch[i] << endl;
            }

        }
        return 0;
    }
```

более простой вариант размер массива можно по желанию увеличить

Comment: конечно минус что тип данных не строка

Answer (score -1):

Используй `regex_iterator` или `regex_token_iterator`